# How to find pairs in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing original records and cancelled records. The original records are marked with code=1 and the cancelled ones are marked with code=2. There are other types of codes as well. I need to find all the original records that do not have a cancellation record in the table.

E.g. Table1

```
id | column2 | column3 | code
-- |-------- | ------- | ---
 1 | abc     | def     | 1
 2 | xyz     | pqr     | 1
 3 | abc     | def     | 2
```

The result of the query should be the row with id 2 as it has not been cancelled.

I am trying to use self-join

```
select * 
from table1 t1
 join table1 t2 on t1.column1=t2.column1
               and t1.column2=t2.column2
               and t1.code<t2.code
where not (t1.code=1 and t2.code=2)
```

Comment: @AT-2016 AFAIK the presence of a cancellation cancels the active record, so it should not appear in the result set.

Comment: Since row 1 has a cancellation record in row 3. In this table, a new record is inserted for the cancellation.

Comment: @Tim got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1 AS t1
WHERE   code = 1
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                         FROM   table1 t2
                         WHERE  t2.code = 2
                                AND t2.column2 = t1.column2
                                AND t2.column3 = t1.column3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is preferable to using `NOT EXISTS` becauese it avoids a correlated subquery.  It also uses joins, which means it can take advantage of indices.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.column2,
       t1.column3,
       t1.code
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT column2,
           column3
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY column2,
             column3
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN code = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
) t2
    ON t1.column2 = t2.column2 AND
       t1.column3 = t2.column3
```

Comment: Not sure the join vs subquery question makes a difference to use of indices. See http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join for example.

Comment: @GavinCampbell I'm not suggesting that an index can only be used in a join, but my approach avoids a correlated subquery, always a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE.
Find sum of code as it is integer. If it is greater than 1, it means somewhere for this value there is 2.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    Select column1,column3 from Table1
    GROUP BY column1,column3
    HAVING SUM(code)=1
)

SELECT t.id,CTE.* FROM CTE
INNER JOIN @temp t ON t.column1=CTE.column1 AND t.column3=CTE.column3
```

Please let me know if it helps.